# Wrong text render on safari in react project

Tags: reactjs, safari

Safari mobile browser have something wrong dealing with text diff and reload. I can't find this issue on google, react issues or stackoverflow.
I just add a unique key on every wrong rendered element, this correct the issue.

Is there any better solution, or I can do something specific for safari to solve this?

Comment: What was the issue in safari mobile browser? You are saying adding unique key corrected the issue so it looks like its moreover a warning but not an issue.

Comment: No, it's an issue, I know there's a key warning in react.
I use a index key on array elements, It's not the right way to use key but it works well on other browsers.
But on safari, the old long text was not totally removed and they appear in my new state of view. Some container element also remains a wrong old bottom line when I change my state and replaced a css class on it.
I use a unique key so react remove the whole element, rather than change the inside text or class on the container, then everything goes right.